# MATLAB vectorization of expression

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Can the inner loop be vectorized? If so, how?

```
for M=1:n_iter
    for k=1:length(v)
        v(k) = min(v(k), (v( max(k − M,1) ) + v( min(k + M,length(v)) ))/2 );
    end
end
```

The problem is how to construct a vector from with the iteration variable k

```
(v( min(k − M,1) ) + v( max(k + M,length(v)) ))/2
```

I wanted to try the SNIP algorithm before implementing it in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, vectorizing a loop simply requires to replace the loop with an vector:

```
for M=1:n_iter
  k=1:length(v)
  v(k) = min(v(k), (v( max(k − M,1) ) + v( min(k + M,length(v)) ))/2 );
end
```